# Where to use CodeIgniter HTML table?

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding where this would go in CodeIgniter's application. I want to pull down some data from MySQL and display it in an HTML table.

I know how to define models and how to write views ... my only question is:

Should I create the HTML (call `$this->table->generate();`) in my View or my Controller?

Comment: *(reference)* http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Comment: @Gordon I saw it,and read it completely before asking question.please read my question again.

Comment: your question is vague at best. What is Table? Db Table? What is Table Library? What parse? And what does it have to do with folders? Please update your question with many more details. Point out what you tried so far and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely generate the table in the view. `$this->table->generate()` returns HTML so I would pass the database result to the view and work with it there with the rest of your HTML.